# CarrierWave/Cloudinary cached images not working across form redisplays in dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

When the form has an error the cached image isn't displayed.  It is trying to go to Cloudinary servers and download an image which doesn't exist.

Here is what the source ends up as:

```
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="guide_image">Image</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <img alt="Ho97jzyhfjludw129u8m" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/memorycommit/image/upload/ho97jzyhfjludw129u8m.jpg" />
            <input class="form-control" id="guide_image" name="guide[image]" type="file" />
            <input id="guide_image_cache" name="guide[image_cache]" type="hidden" value="1402249607-3970-6368/mountain-top-med.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my view code for the image:

```
       <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :image, class: "col-sm-3 control-label" %>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <%= image_tag(@guide.image_url) if @guide.image? %>
            <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
            <%= f.hidden_field(:image_cache) %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  version :standard do
    process :resize_to_fill => [220, 220, :north]
  end

  version :thumbnail do
    resize_to_fit(120, 120)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `cl_image_tag` method doesn't support returning a local URL (such as the image from the `image_cache`).

Comment: I am confused....what is the `cl_image_tag`?  I am using `image_tag`.  Is that the same thing?  If so...do you have any suggestions on what I should use instead?